# BLDC motor inverter function

Tags: simulation, inverter, brushless-dc-motor

I would like to know which inverter function is correct for BLDC motor model simulation.

I want to create mathematical model of this scheme:
[image]

where BLDC motor model is created based on "http://webfiles.portal.chalmers.se/et/MSc/BaldurssonStefanMSc.pdf".

I have seen several proposition of inverter functions. First one is from earlier link:
[image]

But it gives currents signals other than ideal (4 levels instead of 3):
[image]

Other source:
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l60p4G7Bdi0&t=3s"
Shows another inverter function which gives currents signals more similar to ideal (3 levels)
[image]

I would like to know which version is correct and why.

Simulation was runned for:
R=12.5
L=0.91
Ke=0.01
J=0.005
Kt=0.01
Kf=0.0000000138
p=2
TL=0
Vs=6

Comment: Neither is "correct" - they're both *ancient* attempts at *approximation*.  Any modern system would use a PWM output which would in effect much more closely approximate the design ideal for a given motor (which depends on the motor type!) but would do so with a switching waveform not pretty to look at.

Comment: So instead of these functions I need to implement PWM signal that should control, but I don't understand how it should work. Do you have any reliable source that shows step by step how to implement BLDC motor model?

Comment: More you want to look up what the ideal waveform is for your motor.  In an actual driver you'd then approximate the *effect* of that waveform with PWM, depending on the fidelity of your simulation you could either model the ideal waveform or the actual PWM one.

Comment: I took a look on linked document, very comprehensive well described, but there are no 4 levels as you mention. The document describes  chopper switching and PWM switching.

Comment: Ok but I still don't understand one thing. Whether or not I use PWM signal isn't relevant to me yet, because (from what I know) PWM is sort of like input signal (we can replace Vs DC source with PWM signal) that goes into inverter which drives it into active phases of BLDC motor. Still I am not sure how to model inverter function in order to get correct ideal signal waveforms.